# OpenGL C++ SDL 2D Shadows

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d, shadow, light

Currently I'm working on my game, I'm stuck with lights and shadows. 
I figured out how to make shadows with only 1 light source, but how to do it if you have more light sources? How to pass OpenGL 8 light sources limit?

I'm working with C++, OpenGL and SDL.

[These](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mVlYsGOkkyM) two [videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fsbECSpwtig) show exactly what i want.

Comment: What algorithm are you using for shadows? It's projected shadow or shadow volumes..?

Comment: Sorceror, i think that you mean "shadow mapping" instead of projected shadow

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to skip all the tutorials about fixed function pipeline and go straight to the GL3.3+ era: see: https://github.com/McNopper/OpenGL for some tutorials.

Anyway, if you are talking about shadow-mapping, then *you* decide how many lights an object can support (even on a per-object basis) and in **your shader**:

- receive one shadow map for each supported light
- receive one set of light parameters for each supported light
- at each pixel determine if the light is visible, *for each light*
- if the light is visible (not in shadow), calculate the contribution of the light
- sum all the contributions for the final luminance value

Comment: The link is broken now.